# GAE DataStore query filter in JAVA with Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL unable to compare with numeric value

Tags: java, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a query with selects only the Entities with specific numeric value in their property but the following Filter returns an empty result

```
Filter tmpFilter = new Query.FilterPredicate("cost", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, 10);
```

I have several entities that should be selected, I have tried to send the "10" as a string but still no luck.

When I try to select with **GREATER_THAN** or other filter operators then it works.

I have tried to run EQUAL on a string value and it worked but not on a numeric value.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer values are stored as Long in the Datastore. Try 10L instead of 10.

Comment: Wow it worked !!! The other solution I used was ** Query.FilterOperator.IN** instead of EQUAL, but at least now I know that this was the issue !!! Thanks for the fast replay !!!